# NetBeans refactor class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: netbeans, refactoring, classnotfoundexception

I just came across an error when using NetBeans, and I wanted to post my findings (possible this is old news). Perhaps this will save some people the headache of debugging a similar problem that I just encountered. I don't think I'm abusing anything here... stack overflow's SEO is pretty good :)

I refactored a class in NetBeans (JavaFX project), and from that point on I got a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" for that particular refactored class.

I fixed the error by simply doing a "Clean and Build Project." This apparently deleted whatever cache file or erroneous file/class reference. I don't think this is a Netbeans bug... hoping it was just one of those "flukey" moments.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have those issues from time to time when I write new code (or create new code). This is because I use the 'build' function instead of 'clean & build'.

Most of the time, the proper set of class is compiled (or recompiled), but there are situations where newly compiled classes are not compatible with already compiled classes. That's when I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Not a big deal. Just need to clean and recompile everything.